# Why is `? super` used for handler in javafx Node.setOnKeyPressed​(EventHandler<? super KeyEvent> value)?

Tags: java, generics, javafx

I am reading the JavaFX 11 [Node API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html) and can't understand why `EventHandler` often uses generics, as in `<? super Event>`.

For example:

```
Node.setOnKeyPressed(EventHandler<? super KeyEvent> value)
```

why not simply

```
Node.setOnKeyPressed(EventHandler<KeyEvent> value)
```

Could anyone explain this?

Comment: `EventHandler` has a single method - `handle(T)`. There is no reason to require that `T` is a `KeyEvent` - any handler that can handle a `KeyEvent` will do. For example, an `EventHandler<Event>` would do, because all `KeyEvent`s are also `Event`s. As with all (appropriate) usages of wildcards, it makes the API a bit more flexible.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you for your explanation. But I ask you to remove `duplicate` as the main idea of this question is when/in what cases do we need `API a bit more flexible`.

Comment: For a contrived example, say you wanted to count how many times a node receives input. Instead of duplicating code you create a single `EventHandler<InputEvent>`. But for some reason you decide to only count key pressed events for some arbitrary node. Because of the generic signature you could call `setOnKeyPressed` with your `EventHandler<InputEvent>`. Otherwise, you'd have to create a wrapper and filter out non-key-pressed events and delegate.

Comment: Personally, it'd be _less understandable_ if the API _didn't_ provide this flexibility. Even if the designers at the time couldn't think of use cases, that doesn't mean application developers couldn't. Imagine if you wanted the flexibility and it wasn't there? Having the flexibility doesn't inconvenience anyone, whereas not having the flexibility might.

Comment: @Pavel_K "when/in what cases" consider using wildcards for method parameters *pretty much* always, at least in public APIs. The only reason not to use them is if the syntax becomes unduly burdensome. See *Effective Java* (for example) for an in-depth discussion.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: @Pavel_K "the only reason" the other reason is if you actually need the invariance, e.g. you want a list to both produce and consume in the same method (`List<T>` is the intersection of `List<? extends T>` and `List<? super T>`).

Comment: @Slaw BTW could you say - can we add multiple event handlers to one node. For example this way: `buttonFoo.setOnKeyPressed(inputEventHandler); buttonFoo.setOnKeyPressed(keyPressedHandler);`?

Comment: Not via the `onXXX` properties. Setting those properties will replace the previous value. You could do it via `addEventHandler`, however.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AndyTurner I understood your idea. Thank you for your comments.